# BLDC Motor question

Tags: driver, brushless-dc-motor, torque, rpm

Im looking for a solution, i have a 3kW 320V 3000rpm rated BLDC motor with position hall encoder and a chinese driver. The hall-feedback is working with it.

I would like to use motor between 15 and 3000rpm, but unfortunately the motor ripples and stucks under 300rpm.

I have tried the motor from a optidrive e3 frequency driver in bldc vector mode, but there is still a problem with low rpms.

With a 3000rpm rated motor what is the minimal usable rpm with usable torque?

Or if BLDC is not good for this, what kind of motor can I use to reach 15-3000rpm range?

My problem is to use only a motor without a gearbox.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your VFD can't detect the pole passing with back EMF sensing (sensorless BLDC control). This issue is common for all sensorless BEMF sensing devices, even when using induction motor. 15 rpm is very low speed, so you would need an ESC with hall sensors feedback.

Comment: The chinese BLDC driver has the hall feedback. It doesnt work if not connected, so the feedback is working. The other doesnt have.

The chinese one is: Lanjiu LKHPBL3000